# Remove Duplicate Characters from String r

Tags: r

I've got a vector of strings which is being read in, but every entry has garbage characters at the start and end of the string that I want to remove. My problem is that I don't know which characters are the garbage until they appear in each entry.

ie:
Vector contains:

nRsp ;A810SS-Q1D-01 "

nRsp ;C5A19A60WESD04 "

nRsp ;461961  "

in this case, nRsp ; is the garbage at the beginning and " is the end garbage. The garbage values should occur at the same place relative to the start and end of the vector, but I need some way to first find them and then remove them.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it always `nRsp ;` at the beginning?

Comment: No, it will be a different set of characters each time the program is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the characters that all elements of your vector have in common both at the beginning and at the end before removing them, you could do:

```
library(purrr)
## Replicating the data
v = c("nRsp ;A810SS-Q1D-01 \"","nRsp ;C5A19A60WESD04 \"","nRsp ;461961 \"")
## Split each string into a vector
l = strsplit(v,"")
## Find the common parts at the start and end of all elements in the list
start = 1 
while(every(l,function(x) sum(x[1:start]==l[[1]][1:start])==start)){start=start+1}
end = 1
while(every(l,function(x) sum(rev(x)[1:end]==rev(l[[1]])[1:end])==end)){end=end+1}
## Remove the common 'garbage' from each element of the list
v2 = sapply(l,function(x) paste(x[start:(length(x)-end+1)],collapse=""))
```

This returns:

```
[1] "A810SS-Q1D-01"  "C5A19A60WESD04" "461961"
```